# Let $G$ be a group and $H = \{x^{-1}\mid x\in G\}$. Show $G=H$.

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $H = \{x^{-1}\mid x\in G\}$. Show $G=H$.

I have showed that $H \subseteq G$.

Can somebody give me a hint to show how an arbitrary $x \in G$ also belongs in $H$?

Comment: Given an arbitrary element $g \in G$, you wish to somehow write it as $g=x^{-1}$.  I wonder what $x$ is.

Comment: What defining property of G could show that arbitrary element g $\in$ H?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Axiom of Inverse Element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)), if $a\in G$, then $b\in G$ if $a* b=b* a=e$, where $*$ represents the groupg operation. Hence the rest of the proof goes as follows:
$$a\in G\implies a^{-1}\in G\implies (a^{-1})^{-1}\in H\implies a\in H\implies G\subseteq H$$

Comment: I am still unable to show how $a \in H$.

Comment: I added more detail. Hope it help..

Comment: So this is what @Randall was hinting at. Thanks Mostafa

Comment: Yes it is. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Conside the map $G \to G$ given by $x \mapsto x^{-1}$. Prove that this map is an involution, that is, is its own inverse. Conclude that the map is a bijection and so is a surjection.

Comment: I have proved that the map is a bijection but I am unable to see your guidance.

Comment: @KevinDudeja, if the map is a bijection then it is a surjection.